# vb.net read text from web .txt file and show it in textbox?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to read few number from internet .txt file and show it in text box, but without result...

These systems are imported:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Net
```

Here is the code of reading file:

```
Dim address As String = "http://www.url.com/text.txt"
Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
Dim reply As String = client.DownloadString(address)
TextBox2.Text = reply
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
Dim address As String = "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(client.OpenRead(address))
Textbox2.Text = reader.ReadToEnd
```

Comment: Thanks, worked for me. I forgot to set private sub on LOAD, now works like a charm.